My physical iPad no longer showing as an option in debug
This still kind of works, but it's showing run on "Windows Machine" in the device list, but it still deploys to my physical iPad and runs in debug.  I'm pretty sure I didn't make any code changes that would have done this; I haven't been working in this code for a few weeks and just returned to it.  I know it was working when I was last in the code.
--- also, this was never a windows app and it was removed from the list about a year ago---
I'm not sure if this occurred after a VS update; I'm currently on VS 2022 17.10.3.
I'm able to connect up to my Mac to compile.
It used to show my iPad in the list for debugging as well as software OS devices.
I did some searches out there but didn't find anything, I guess I'm not even sure what I should be searching on.


Repair VS may fixes the issue, and upgrade XCode to the latest compatible version, then consider upgrading to Version 17.11.0 Preview 2.0

That was it, I didn't realize that the device info came from XCode on the Mac! Thanks!

Glad it works, kindly post your answer to close this question. Thanks!

Although you have mentioned it in the question could you still please tag the specific version of Visual Studio

The answer was to upgrade the XCode on the Mac.
